# Change the variable with the passage of the line point

Tags: graphics, animation

How can I make dynamic change of the variable `q` with the passage of the line point? When red line get to the blue point, the coordinate of point is changing to coordinates of blue line. Or when 'q' == 'x'; q = x - x/10.. Thank you.

```
q = 45 Degree
Animate[Graphics[{{Red, Point[{2.9 Cos[q], 2.9 Sin[q]}]}, {Blue, 
    Point[{3 Cos[45 Degree], 3 Sin[45 Degree]}]}, {Red, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x], 3 Sin[x]}}]}, {Blue, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x - x/10], 3 Sin[x - x/10]}}]}}, 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {x, 0, 12 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: `How can I make dynamic change of the variable q with the passage of the line point` sorry, but having hard time understanding the question. What exactly do you mean? Can you explain more what you want? How should the point change? You also probably want to add `Degree` to your `q` and your `12[Pi]` is not correct syntax.

Comment: Oh, sorry. When red line get to the blue point, the coordinate of point is changing to coordinates of blue line. Or when 'q' == 'x'; q = x - x/10. All errors corrected!

Answer (score 1):

*Update*: this is a bit of a kluge but I think at least this time it does what you requested.

```
q = 45 Degree;
Animate[
 If[x == 0, sol = (5 π)/18; 
  bp = {3 Cos[x′ - x′/10], 3 Sin[x′ - x′/10]} /. 
    x′ -> sol];
 If[x >= sol,
  bp = {3 Cos[x′ - x′/10], 3 Sin[x′ - x′/10]} /. 
    x′ -> sol; 
  sol = Solve[{3 Cos[x′], 3 Sin[x′]} == bp][[1, 1, 2, 1]];
  sol = sol /. C[1] -> ⌈Solve[sol == x][[1, 1, 2]]⌉;
  ];
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], {Red, Point[{2.9 Cos[q], 2.9 Sin[q]}]}, {Blue, 
    Point[bp]}, {Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x], 3 Sin[x]}}]}, {Blue, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {3 Cos[x - x/10], 3 Sin[x - x/10]}}]}}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, PlotLabel -> (N@{x, sol})], {x, 0, 24 Pi, 0.1}, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRate -> 20]
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand, why the point change its coordinates only 2 times?

Comment: @YuMo I think I misunderstood your question.  I thought you meant when the red line is *exactly on* the blue point, move the blue point.  After the second pass the point is at `{3 Cos[Pi/400], 3 Sin[Pi/400]}` and `Pi/40` is insufficient resolution to hit this position.  Reading your question again I believe you want the point to move every time the line passes the point, even if it does not land exactly on it in a particular animation frame.  I'll have to think about that.

Comment: Maybe exist more logical way to solve this problem? Or enter the interval in condition.

Comment: @YuMo After a few minutes consideration I do not see how we can *accurately* move the blue point as the line sweeps past without solving for the intersection.  I mean that if we merely detect that the line is on the other side of the point and move the point to where the blue line is at that "time" (value of x) it will not be at the true moment of collision between the red line and the point.  Have you already considered that approach?

Comment: If you asking about approach with intersection, i didn't try it. I tried to increase Pi/40 and it slowly works correct, but it is not suitable. And how do you. Do you have any thoughts about approach with intersection? I have no ideas.

Comment: @YuMo I am too tired now to give a better answer.  I shall try to return to this tomorrow, but hopefully someone else gives a satisfying answer before then.

Comment: @YuMo Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @mr-wizard DId this solution works after third rotation? Could anybody check this solution? My comp crashed after third rotation

Comment: @YuMo Yes, it does work past the third rotation on my system: version 10.1.0 under Windows 7.  What are you using?

Comment: @mr-wizard version 10.4 under Windows 10. I'll try this on working station. Thank you